# $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ as a complex Lie group

Tags: complex-analysis, lie-groups

Using the simplest definition of a complex Lie group, I want to show that $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ is a complex Lie group by first showing that its product map (i.e. $(A,B)\mapsto AB$) is holomorphic.

I'm trying to teach myself about complex Lie groups, but I'm a bit unsure of how this sort of map can be shown to be holomorphic. I've taken complex analysis, but only in one variable so I'm a bit stuck. Any advice is much appreciated!

I've considered a partial derivative like in real multivariable calculus, but I am not sure if this is the correct approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof really works just about the same as in the real valued case, appropriately generalized, as with much of Complex Analysis. So you can really use the answer [for this question linked here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1443036/prove-that-matrix-multiplication-and-inversion-is-differentiable) and make the necessary modifications. Essentially, ignoring the determinant condition, 'most basic properties' about matrix multiplication are 'nice' because each entry in the product can be considered as a polynomial functions (or rational functions) in entries from the factors in the product.

Comment: In the answer you linked, I see that $(AB)_{ij}$ is clearly a polynomial, but why does this imply that $g$ is a polynomial itself?

Comment: @bowlofpetunias I think it's just an abuse of language. They aren't saying $g$ is $a$ polynomial, rather that it is (given by) polynomial(s). For example, if $A,B$ are 2x2 with entries $a_1,\ldots,a_4, b_1,\ldots,b_4$, respectively. Then We can think of the product $C= AB$ having entries $(c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4)$ given by $g(a_1,\ldots,b_4)= (a_1b_1+a_2b_3,\ldots,a_3b_2+a_4b_4)=(c_1,\ldots,c_4)$, which each entry in the function is polynomial in the total number of entries for $A,B$. Apologies for a bit vague entry labeling, I was too lazy to go through the whole double subscript.